# PHP, Sessions with out cookie and url parameter

Tags: php

I'm creating a client for protocol running over TCP/IP sockets,the protocol is request/respond but unlike HTTP, any party can initiate the request and get back respond.
The protocol is session oriented and passes state between requests in its header fields. So I would like to build upon PHP native sessions management to manage sessions and avoid having to re-invent the wheel.
But PHP sessions were build with http protocol in mind and assumes client capabilities related to sessions handling. For example

```
 session_start();
```

The above line sends a session cookie to the browser or in case `session.use_cookies='0'` is set sends url parameter.

The question is now, is there way PHP can be forced to use `session id` given in the code at run time or retrieved from other storage locations to get current session data.
something like this.

```
//start session in index.php
  session_start();

// somewhere in other pages
  set_active_session_id('47f6ac750'); // magical function
   $name = $_SESSION['name'] // works as normal
```

So, in other words, I want to use php sessions outside HTTP protocol.To be precise, on the CLI.

Answer (score 2):

[`session_id()`](https://secure.php.net/session_id) can be used to set the session ID. And it does it before the session is started, which will save you a ton of headaches.

I just hope you're only doing this for educational purposes, because it sounds horrible.

Comment: So `session_id()` sets the session id that will be used to get values in $_SESSION.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what you asked for.